# Unicode "icons" render differently on different PCs? (Win7 vs. Win10)

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, unicode, .net-4.7.2

I have some `MenuItem`s which use Unicode symbols as their icons.

On my Windows 10 development PC, they all work fine. But on a Windows 7 test virtual machine, only some of them do.

This one works all the time:

```
                            <MenuItem Command="...">
                                <MenuItem.Header>
                                    <Run FontStyle="Italic">Header Text...</Run>
                                </MenuItem.Header>
                                <MenuItem.Icon>
                                    <Span FontSize="15">✎</Span>
                                </MenuItem.Icon>
                            </MenuItem>
```

But this one fails on Win7:

```
                            <MenuItem
                                Header="Up"
                                Icon="⮝"
                                Command="..."
                                />
```

Instead it displays a rectangle in place of the expected symbol.

At first I suspected a missing font but as you can see in the code, no font family is being specified at all.

---

Its an involved build process to get the app onto the Win7 test virtual machine, so its laborious to troubleshoot this by trial and error. I don't have a dev environment that can reproduce it.

It might not be Win10 vs. Win7 that is the cause at all, but so far that's all I have to go on.

This is a .NET 4.7.2 project.

---

I also just noticed another case of failure on Win7:

```
                <Button
                    Command="..."
                    >
                    <TextBlock
                        FontSize="20"
                        FontFamily="Arial"
                        Margin="0,-3,0,0"
                        >
                        
                    </TextBlock>
                </Button>
```

This one also is OK on Win10, but shows a rectangle in place of the  on Win7.

Comment: There have been several changes between Win7 and Win10 about fonts, fallback and linking, see [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/input/font-technology), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/input/font-support).

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to find a satisfying "root cause" of this problem and instead ended up with an acceptable image-based workaround. However I thought it would be useful to at least document what I had tried.

Attempts to investigate / solve:

- The fonts being used for the symbols with issues were both Arial &
  Segoe UI. These both existed on the working Win10 and non-working
  Win7 environments.
- Watching the app in Win7 with Process Monitor, I could see the fonts
  being loaded from disk. No errors or missing items.
- Noting that the font version (properties on the font file) were older
  on Win7, I copied the Win10 fonts to the Win7 PC and installed them.
  But this had no effect on the problem.

---

Given that none of that worked (and was consuming a lot of time) I elected to change my XAML design to use images instead in the cases where there were problems.

To reproduce the same visual look as closely as possible I created SVG drawings with Inkscape that were based on the same font & symbols. After added a text element with the desired symbol, I then converted it to a path (for further use as an SVG). (It could also be exported as a bitmap at this point in the same final size as the font symbol, though I didn't need to do this as I was using SVG images directly already.)

I then substituted `<Image>` elements in place of the text objects which had been used before.